# Does anyone know why we use yield return in the GetClientValidationRules() implementation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have seen many examples and I am implementing a custom unobtrusive validator. I am confused by seeing `yield return` being used to return one ModelClientValidationRule in the `GetClientValidationRules()` method.
Does anyone know why is it used - is GetClientValidationRules called for each rule sequentially or is it supposed to return the whole collection at once?

I am sure the way I am using it here, I can just replace it with a `return` statement:

```
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var validationParameters = base.GetClientValidationParameters()
                .Union(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, object>("requiredproperties", string.Join(",", RequiredProperties)) });
            var validationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName),
                ValidationType = this.GetValidationType()
            };
            foreach(var kvp in validationParameters)
            {
                validationRule.ValidationParameters.Add(kvp.Key.ToLowerInvariant(), kvp.Value);
            }
            yield return validationRule;
        }
```

Can someone explain if this is correct or is there a better way to return validation rules here?

Comment: As there is only one `ModelClientValidationRule` and there is no deferred execution happening, I suspect there is no performance difference. The use of `yield return validationRule;` means you do not have to create a collection - otherwise you could use `return new[] { validationRule};

Comment: @StephenMuecke But instead of creating a collection, it probably creates an enumerator class for the function :) Feels a bit pointless in this case to use `yield`.

Comment: @juunas, Yes, internally its creating a collection. And as I noted, I suspect there is no difference (although all the source code I have looked at seem to use `yield`)

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I'm more concerned about which scenario would require us to return an enumerable instead of just one ModelClientValidationRule?